# Force ExtJS application to update after deployment

Tags: extjs, build, jenkins

Are there any known procedures to achieve this. Application is being automatically build by Jenkins. Only possible way I could remember is changing file names but this is not preferable option.

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280812/2935802

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for cache manifest file. Ext 5 production build already contains some basic setup, however, you would need to adjust it to your needs.

Rule of thumb: **If the manifest file changes, the app is refreshed.**

For more info see [A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) or google for "cache manifest".